# Using caching system for hundred thousands of rows

Tags: caching

I need a fast short term memory being able to contain tons of data. I was obviously thinking about using my framework's caching system or Redis. However, even though, the data I am gonna store in the cache will expire after 10 minutes, I may need to store hundred of thousands rows at a time. Is a caching system appropriate for a such job, or should I look into a db solution here ?